# Find the general solution to these partial differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution to these partial differential equations?

(b) $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} - u = e^{x-y} $

(c) $u_{xx} + y^2u = 0 $

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The first one is first order and linear - best tackled with the method of characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\partial_y u - u = \mathrm{e}^{x-y}
$$
$$
u\mathrm{e^{-y}} = \int \mathrm{e}^{x-y}\mathrm{e}^{-y}dy + g(x) = \int \mathrm{e}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{-2y}dy + g(x)
$$
$$
u(x,y) = -\mathrm{e}^{y}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{-2y} + g(x)\mathrm{e}^{y} = -\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{e}^{x-y} + g(x)\mathrm{e}^{y}
$$
where $g(x)$ is a function determined from conditions of the problem.

the next you can do as a similar fashion, by integrated as you would do for the 1-D problem but treat constants as that of the variable we are not integrating with, and it should lead to 
$$
u(x,y) = A(y)\cos\left(yx\right) + B(y)\sin\left(yx\right)
$$